# Remove duplicates in mongodb find

Tags: javascript, mongodb, find, aggregate

I have the following find query, which returns all the products with the matching storeIDs

```
numberOfUniqueProducts =  await this.productStoreModel.find({store: { $in: storeIDs }}).lean()
```

However, I want to filter this to remove duplicate products. I have managed to do this in a filter function, however i was wondering if it could be done in the find itself?

```
let numberOfUniqueProducts = numberOfUniqueProducts.filter(
(v, i, a) => a.findIndex((t) => t.product === v.product) === i
);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insted of find you can use this.productStoreModel.distinct({store: { $in: storeIDs }}).

This will give you distinct data.

for more info Click [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)!

Comment: Will that check for unique product IDs on each document though?